# Dynamically loading ipod drill down

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, user-experience, drilldown

I have a need for the user to classify a support incident they are submitting. The available classifications are hierarchical in nature with an unfixed number of levels. As far as I can tell, the type of data lends itself nicely to a drill-down styled control.

I was playing around, quick successfully up to a point, with https://github.com/mewsoft/Bootstrap-DrillDownMenu but ran into a problem that seems to be common with all of other derivatives out there. Lack of support for dynamically loading the tree. Looking through the code, they all seem to based on the initialization concept of analyzing all the existing li elements, calculating heights and widths, and then setting negative margins (and thus manipulating said margins) to hide and show the currently active sub-menu.

This outright does not work when the data is loaded on-demand. And I rather not have to write my own plugin and make extensive modifications to an existing.

I guess this posting for several related threads...

1. Can anybody think of a reason why the general approach to drilldown (and maybe this is specific to ipod-styled versions) is to use calculated widths and negative margins to hide/show as opposed to display:none and width:100% as needed?
2. Can anybody recommend an active (or relatively active) plugin that provides the following features

   - Dynamically loading of tree elements
   - Breadcrumb of selected element
   - Supports integration with Bootstrap styling (or any framework for that matter)
   - Works on desktop browser or on mobile device (responsive)
3. <s>In 2015, is drilldown still considered an acceptable (efficient) way for allowing users to view/manipulate/select an item from a hierarchy? Is there a better UX approach?</s> This question moved to https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/84812/modern-way-of-viewing-selecting-dynamically-loaded-hierarchal-data based on recommendation.

Comment: You may want to consider asking #3 on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ you will likely get a better answer there.

Comment: Thank you @Schmalzy... I was not aware of that community. Will do so now.